# Find missing value in a numbers sequence - DGV column

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, max

I tried searching and didn't have any success in fixing my problem so I tried finding my own solution.

First I found max (Max) value (min value is always 1), then I set loop to search value by value, but something is wrong with my loop.

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To Max
        For y As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(0).Value = i Then

            Else
                builder2.Append(i & ",")

            End If
        Next
    Next
```

To me loop looks OK but it's not working. If value `i` is found do nothing if it's not found add `i` to `stringbuilder`, and so on until it reaches `Max` value. But whatever combination I've tried I get some weird results.

Numbers are sorted from lowest to highest.

I've also extracted all values from DGV column to comma delimited string if it's easier that way...

EDIT : 
Just for experimenting with that loop I've put i = 40 to 50 (to reduce the range). I know that missing values in DGV column are 40-46 and 59.
This is what I've got with loop above : 
[image]

Comment: *what* are you trying to do?  all that does is test if `Cell(0)` matches the current index.  what do you want it to do? how does it fail? define the technical term "weird results" ... there is nothing there regarding the "search value"

Comment: I have 1 column in DGV with whole numbers, after determining max value I am looping all numbers from 1 to Max through DGV column to find if some of those values in range (1 to Max) are missing from DGV.

Comment: I've edited original post for better explanation of those weird results. I've also tried 'Exit for' and 'i = i+1' inside condition but results didn't improve.

Comment: your process is flawed: there is no reason to Loop `Max` times when an If statement will do.  the terms Min, Max and range imply you want to test if  `Max > Cells(0) > Min` but what does "missing" mean? EDIT: ok, by 'missing' do you mean the value is not in the defined range?

Comment: Max is just the name of the dim statement and i represents all values that should be in DGV column. But some values maybe missing, so I am trying to find what numerical values in sequence are not in DGV column. Example : 4 is missing in 1-2-3-5 sequence and I would like for that 4 to be in shown at the end of that loop. Since mine goes to 1000 or more manual counting and searching for missing numbers would be almost impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to find missing numbers quite easily. You just need to get the existing numbers into a List, and then you can use `Max()` to find the largest number, and `Except()` to find the missing ones.

I put a DGV named DataGridView1 with one column, a button named bnPopulateDGV, and a button named bnFindMissingNumbers on a new Windows Form, and used the following code (with `Option Infer On`):

```
Private Sub bnPopulateDGV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnPopulateDGV.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    Dim seq1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList()
    Dim rand As New Random
    ' knock some out
    For i = 1 To 5
        seq1.RemoveAt(rand.Next(0, 50))
    Next
    For Each s In seq1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {s.ToString()})
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub bnFindMissingNumbers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnFindMissingNumbers.Click
    Dim existingNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        existingNumbers.Add(CInt(r.Cells(0).Value))
    Next
    Dim min = 1
    Dim max = existingNumbers.Max()
    Dim missingNumbers = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Except(existingNumbers)
    MsgBox("Missing: " & String.Join(", ", missingNumbers))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have to figure out how did you do that :)

Comment: @Jovica The only problem is that in 3.5, `String.Join` takes an array of strings as the entity to be joined, and only that. All you have to do is devise some other way of listing the numbers.

Comment: Thank you again. Now, it's also working in 3.5 with StringBuilder.

Comment: @Jovica You're welcome :) Another way to get the missing numbers into an array of strings and then joined would be to use `String.Join(", ", missingNumbers.Select(Function(n) n.ToString()).ToArray())`.